# the trait `FromSegments<'_>` is not implemented for `rocket::form::Form<ContentsRequest>`

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

when I add the form request in rust rocket `rocket = { version = "=0.5.0-rc.2", features = ["json"] }` like this:

```
#[get("/page/<path..>")]
fn get_page(path: Form<ContentsRequest>) {  }
```

the compiler shows error like this:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `rocket::form::Form<ContentsRequest>: FromSegments<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:21:19
   |
21 | fn get_page(path: Form<ContentsRequest>) {  }
   |                   ^^^^ the trait `FromSegments<'_>` is not implemented for `rocket::form::Form<ContentsRequest>`
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fixed it? This is the full `main.rs` code:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

use rocket::form::Form;
use rocket_okapi::{mount_endpoints_and_merged_docs, rapidoc::*, swagger_ui::*};
use rocket_okapi::settings::UrlObject;
use rocket::serde::Deserialize;
use rocket::serde::Serialize;


#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![get_page])
}


#[get("/page/<path..>")]
fn get_page(path: Form<ContentsRequest>) {  }


use rocket_okapi::okapi::schemars::JsonSchema;
use rocket_okapi::okapi::schemars;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize, FromForm, JsonSchema)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct ContentsRequest {
    /// The contents_type
    contents_type: i32
}
```

and this is the `Cargo.toml` dependencies:

```
[package]
name = "rust-demo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "=0.5.0-rc.2", features = ["json"] }

okapi = { git = "https://github.com/GREsau/okapi.git"}
schemars = "0.7"
rocket_okapi = { git = "https://github.com/GREsau/okapi.git", features = ["swagger", "rapidoc"] }


serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
serde_derive = "1.0"
# database
diesel = { version = "1.4.7", features = ["postgres","serde_json"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
jsonwebtoken = "7"
chrono = "0.4"
config = "0.11"
ring = "0.16.20"
md5 = "0.7.0"
data-encoding = "2.3.2"
```

Comment: What URLs are you trying to match here? Can you give an example?

Comment: I have not test the url match yet, I want to add some comment on the get parameter with openapi follow the docs from here: https://github.com/GREsau/okapi/pull/26. @Dogbert But could not compile when tweak the parameter.

Comment: maybe it would like `http://xxxx.com/xxxx?contents_type=1` @Dogbert

Comment: Can you try `#[get("/page/?<path..>")]`?

Comment: I have tried what you said but it would not work.@Dogbert

Comment: What error are you getting with `#[get("/page/?<path..>")]`? (Note the `?` after `/`, that's required to match query strings.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245460/discussion-between-dolphin-and-dogbert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to match trailing query parameters is a `?` before `<name..>`. You also don't need to wrap the type in `Form<_>`:

```rust
#[get("/page?<path..>")]
fn get_page(path: ContentsRequest) {}
```

[Docs](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/requests/#trailing-parameter)

Comment: why are u talking about trailing query parameters ? there is no GET parameter present or anything, I just wanted to create a dynamic path like "/books/<topic>/<title>"